# Dynamically Changing HTML

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to create a HTML page where the "body" color changes depending on some data being gathered from the RAM.  If the RAM fills up beyond a certain threshold then I want the color to change.

```
    <body style="background-color:<%=
    if(MemoryPercentage < 33)
    {
        //set to green.
    }
    else if(MemoryPercentage < 66)
    {
        //set to yellow.
    }
    else
    {
            //set to red.
    }%>">
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<body 
    style="background-color:<%= MemoryPercentage < 33? "green":
        (MemoryPercentage < 66? "yellow":"red") %>;">
```

Comment: Thank you!  Being new to this whole mess this answer wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer using CSS classes and separating the logic out so it is more readable.

```
<style type="text/css">
.warn {
   background-color: #00ffff;
}
.error {
   background-color: #ff0000;
}
.ok {
   background-color: #00ff00;
}
</style>

<%
    var klass = MemoryPercentage < 33 : "ok" ? (MemoryPercentage < 66 ? "warn" : "error");
%>

<body class="<%= klass %>">
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I started with the answer above but have since modified my code to reflect your additional CSS tip.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

While you can definitely apply the style directly using the sytle attribute of the body tag (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269540/dynamicly-changing-html/2269548#2269548)), general best practices revolving around HTML discourage this.

What you should do is place these styles in a stylesheet which is referenced on your page, and then have different names for the classes.

Then, in your code, apply the **class** that has the style you want depending on your logic to the class attribute of the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Just an aside to the other answers:

`<body id="Body" runat="server">` will make the tag accessible to `Page_Load()` & friends as an `HtmlGenericControl`, so you can handle the logic and set `Body.CssClass` without the template-y markup.  Makes it a little less messy / easier to maintain.